# Having problems with lex specification

Tags: lex

I'm trying to define a simple tokenizer for a language in lex.

Basically , I want to define tokens for parenthesis, comma, comparison ops, in/con/ncon ops, and logical ops. And I want **any other token** to match the 'keywords' regexp, as that would represent a STRINGARG in my language.

Everytime I try to feed it a string like 'A_FIELD', it gives me a LEXER ERROR. I want it to match 'keywords' and return a STRINGARG token.

Here is my .l file :

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

lparen "("
rparen ")"
comma ","
comparison ("=="|"!="|">"|"<"|">="|"<=")
intok ("in"|"IN")
conncontok ("con"|"CON"|"ncon"|"NCON")
logical ("and"|"or"|"AND"|"OR"|"&"|"|")
keywords ( "(" | ")" | "," | "==" | "!=" | ">" | "<" | ">=" | "<=" | "in" | "IN" | "con" | "CON" | "ncon" | "NCON" | "and" | "AND" | "&" | "or"\
 | "OR" | "|" )

%%

" "                    /* ignore whitespace */
{lparen}               { return LPAREN; }
{rparen}               { return RPAREN; }
{comma}                { return COMMA; }
{comparison}           { yylval.str = yytext; return COMPARISON; }
{intok}                { return IN; }
{conncontok}           { yylval.str = yytext; return CONNCON; }
{logical}              { return LOGICAL; }
^keywords              { yylval.str = yytext; return STRINGARG; }
.                      { printf("LEXER ERROR."); exit(1); }

%%

#ifndef yywrap
int yywrap() { return 1; }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this problem.

Basically I wanted a stringarg to be anything other than one of the recognized tokens. So when I set up my lex definition as follows, everything worked out fine. I should have been using character classes, not tokens in the last rule :

```
%%

" "                    /* ignore whitespace */
{lparen}               { return LPAREN; }
{rparen}               { return RPAREN; }
{comma}                { return COMMA; }
{comparison}           { yylval.str = yytext; return COMPARISON; }
{intok}                { return IN; }
{conncontok}           { yylval.str = yytext; return CONNCON; }
{logical}              { return LOGICAL; }
**[^ \t\n]+              { yylval.str = yytext; return STRINGARG; }**
.                      { printf( "Lexer error." ); exit(1); }
%%
```

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answers so the question doesn't look unanswered.